# How to send back the value sent to the fallback?

Tags: solidity, remix, fallback-function, receive

Is there a way to get and keep the value sent to the fallback/receive functions? Let's say, I want to send back Ethers that sent to my contract. Okay, existence of fallback function is enough to deal with receiving ether but I want to keep value sent to me. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send the amount back to the original sender, you can do this:

```
fallback() external payable {
     address _to = msg.sender;
     (bool success, ) = _to.call{value: msg.value}("");
     require(success, "send failed")
}
```

If you want to send to a specific address, replace the _to.
You might face some complexities due to gas if your contract balance is zero, then send will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The `msg.value` contains the amount of ETH that was received, so you can send that amount back to `msg.sender`.